# memcpy causing 'exc bad access'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, arrays, memcpy

I'm trying to loop through an array and copy across data, but after 1023 loops, I get an `exc bad access` message thrown and I have a feeling it might be to do with my memory.
In my loop, I need to append data to my `totalValues` array, so I did this:

```
memcpy(totalValues + totalCopied, tempBuffer, 600 * sizeof(float));
```

This is done inside a loop and `totalCopied` keeps track of how much data has been appended to `totalValues` so that I know where to write from when the loop hits memcpy again. I'm not sure why I get the "exc bad access" error, but my theory is that the memory is not contiguous and, therefore, the `totalValues + totalCopied` line might be causing trouble. I'm not sure if an error would be thrown in this case, or if the memory would just be overwritten anyway. The interesting thing is, it always occurs after 1023 loops. If I remove the 'memcpy' line, the program loops through without any problems. Any ideas what could be causing this?

EDIT - The cause was that the memory allocation was hard coded for another file. Normally, I won't know the length of the file before the memory allocation, so how can I ensure that enough memory is allocated at runtime?

Comment: does that "1023" number look at all suspicious to you?

Comment: Not initially, but I think NSResponder had spotted the mistake. I think the allocated memory space is not big enough but then the question is how to handle this in a real-life case where the size of the file is not known beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're writing more bytes than totalValues can contain.  Show us how you're allocating it.

Incidentally, we usually do this kind of thing with NSData objects on iOS.

Comment: Aha, I think you've found the problem. When I initially created it, I was using a different file and this was how it was allocated: `float *totalValues = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 600 * 1184);`. But, this leads to another problem. 1184 was hard coded as a test, but how would I be able to do this without knowing the length of the file beforehand?

Comment: Don't try to store all the data in one contiguous block of memory. Instead, come up with some kind of sensible data structure. Alternatively, if the data is too big to fit in the buffer, allocate a buffer of double the size of the existing buffer, copy into the new buffer, free the old buffer, and keep going.

Comment: @David Schwartz: Won't `realloc` do that for you?

Comment: Thank you for the help. So basically, I should set the initial malloc to a reasonable size and then use `realloc` if the loaded file is bigger than the malloc size?