# memcpy returns EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++, ios, c, audio, core-audio

I am trying to copy(obviously) an AudioBufferList into a TPCircularBuffer using `TPCircularBufferCopyAudioBufferList`. However it is returning an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for what seems like no reason. I allocate the buffer

It prints out `(AudioBuffer) [1] = (mNumberChannels = 1, mDataByteSize = 8192, mData = void * = 0x057ba060)` for the AudioBufferList created by `TPCircularBufferPrepareEmptyAudioBufferList` and the in AudioBuffer is described as `(AudioBuffer [1]) mBuffers = {
  [0] = (mNumberChannels = 2, mDataByteSize = 8192, mData = void * = 0x057dc000)
}`. The bytesToCopy was 8192, so I see no reason it should be failing.

The outside code looks like this:

```
TPCircularBufferCopyAudioBufferList(_circularBuffer, bufferList, NULL, kTPCircularBufferCopyAll, &_inputASBD);//Uses bufferList from EZAudioFile
```

I checked and the _circularBuffer was allocated and the ABSD makes no difference because it's copying all frames.

UPDATE:
I noticed that printing the log of the mData returns a TDLogger instance? But the audioBufferList is getting passed straight from EZAudioFile

```
Printing description of inBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData:
<TDLogger: 0x5834000>
```

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623602/memcpy-causing-exc-bad-access, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788763/memcpy-leads-to-exc-bad-access, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144166/why-am-i-getting-exc-bad-access-with-these-c-functions

Comment: @dragosht every duplicate you named I have looked at before and cannot apply to my situation. I have checked that the size of my buffer is big enough. All of those were because of pointers too small or not accessible.